# Creating templates for specific locations in Orchard themes

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Working on a custom theme for Orchard 1.6. I've got my top navigation & recent blogs rendering exactly how I want it. However I want to create a footer that shows the navigation & recent blog posts in a different way. I'm using four zones across the footer and want to add widgets to them (navigation, recent blog posts), however I want the rendering to be different.

I can't figure out how to create a view that is used for these widgets JUST within these zones. The template override options shown in the Shape Tracing tool aren't specific to the zone I'm in so they'd apply to the ones in the body of the site (which I've already implemented).

Is what I'm trying to do even possible w/o some custom code (not just a view but some type of a new component) which I'm trying to avoid?

Comment: Did you enable Widget Alternates?

Comment: I wasn't but now I am... new to this and that was the pointer I needed. Thanks Bertrand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable Widget Alternates, you'll get additional alternates that you can use, in particular depending on the zone name.